# Scala - mapping to functions, struggling against contravariance

Tags: scala, dictionary, covariance, contravariance

Let's say I have

```
trait A
case class S(s:String) extends A
case class B(b:Boolean) extends A
```

And

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,(Seq[C]) => Option[A]](
    "testS" -> ((cs:Seq[C]) => Some(S(foo(cs)))),
    "testB" -> ((cs:Seq[C]) => Some(B(bar(cs)))),
    ...
)
```

Now suppose we have a type `D` such that `D <: C`:

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,(Seq[C]) => Option[A]](
    "testS" -> ((cs:Seq[C]) => Some(S(foo(cs)))),
    "testB" -> ((cs:Seq[C]) => Some(B(bar(cs)))),
    "testD" -> ((ds:Seq[D]) => Some(B(baz(ds.head)))), //oops!
    ...
)
```

Yes, stupid as I am, I forgot (again) that arguments are supposed to be contravariant, meaning

```
D <: C, therefore (C => E) <: (D => E)
```

So of course Scala won't let me do that: "type mismatch"

The whole idea of using a map is that the client should be able to add mappings of his own. I could, of course, simply require that such cases be added like

```
    "testD" -> ((ds:Seq[C]) => Some(B(baz(ds.head.asInstanceOf[D]))))
```

But is that the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `asInstanceOf` is dangerous here.  What if `ds.head` is actually an instance of `D2` for some other `D2 <: C`?  This isn't an issue of contravariance so much as you need to refine your abstraction so that the types make more sense.

You should consider how you're going to use your dictionary `m` – are you trying to apply all of its values to some generic `Seq[C]`?  If so, the client should not be allowed to pass in functions of type `D => E` since those may not apply to all instances of `C`. If each client has its own dictionary where all the methods will have arguments of a single type, then maybe the client instantiation should be generic in some type `X <: C`, and then `m` can include methods from `X => E`.

Certainly more detail is required to come up with a type system that might work here because right now the only natural type for your list of functions is `Any => E`, which is dangerous for its own reason.  Here is a simplified version of your problem that may help elucidate the issue:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
trait C
trait D extends C
val cfunc: C => Int = c => 1
val dfunc: D => Int = d => 1
var list = ListBuffer[C => Int](cfunc)
list += dfunc
```